# PHP - File upload failed due to upload path and save with related path

Tags: php, file-upload

Project folder structure:

jobs

- images
- lib

  - validate.php

Following is the code in `validate.php`

```
<?php

    include('config.php');
    $_SESSION['message'] = '';

    // REGISTER CANDIDATES
    if(isset($_POST['register'])){

        if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmpassword']){

            $fullname       = $_POST['fullname'];
            $phone          = $_POST['phone'];
            $username       = $_POST['username'];
            $email          = $_POST['email'];
            // $pass           = md5($_POST['password']);
            $pass           = password_hash( $_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT );
            $dirname        = dirname(__DIR__) . '/images/'; // this works
            $temp           = explode(".", $_FILES['avatar']['name']);
            $newfilename    = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
            $avatar_path    = $dirname . $newfilename;
            // $avatar_path    = '../images/' . $_FILES['avatar']['name'];

            $fullname       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$fullname);
            $phone          = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$phone);
            $username       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
            $email          = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$email);
            $avatar_path    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$avatar_path);

            if(preg_match("!image!", $_FILES['avatar']['type'])){

                if(copy($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'],$avatar_path)){
                    $_SESSION['username']   = $username;
                    $_SESSION['avatar']     = $avatar_path;

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO candidates (fullname, phone, username, email, pass, avatar) VALUES('$fullname','$phone','$username','$email','$pass', '$avatar_path')";

                    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
                        $_SESSION['message'] = "Registration Successful!";
                        header("location:user.php");
                    } else {
                        $_SESSION['message'] = "User could not be added!";
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "File Upload Failed!";
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Please upload only JPG, PNG or GIF image!";
            }

        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Password did not match!";
        }
    }



    // LOGIN CANDIDATES
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
        $password   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

        if (empty($username)) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Username or email is required";
        }
        if (empty($password)) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Password is required";
        }

        if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
            $password = md5($password);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE username='$username' AND pass='$password'";
            $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
                header('location: user.php');
            } else {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Wrong username/password combination";
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

The problem with the following lines,

```
$dirname        = dirname(__DIR__) . '/images/';
$avatar_path    = $dirname . $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
```

it saves path like `/home/rainpeyi/public_html/demo/jobs/images/Nisha.jpg` which does not work for `img src=""`. I want relative path that retrieves image. It will be great if we could save the path like www.example.com/project-dir/images/img.name

the form is the following:

```
<?php 
    include('lib/validate.php');

    // header
    include('inc/header.php');
?>

<div class="register_form">
    <h2>Create an account</h2>
    <form class="form" action="register.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="alert alert-error"><?= $_SESSION['message'] ?></div>
            <div class="group_row">
                <div class="fullname">
                    <label for="fullname">Full Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Anwer Ashif" name="fullname" required />
                </div>
                <div class="tel">
                    <label for="phone">Mobile or Telephone:</label>            
                    <input type="tel" placeholder="01812-345678" name="phone" required />
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="group_row">
            <div class="username">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="ashif" name="username" required />
            </div>
            <div class="email">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" placeholder="myemail@example.com" name="email" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group_row">
            <div class="password">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="ue$jL382@0l" name="password" autocomplete="new-password" required />
            </div>
            <div class="reenterpass">
                <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="ue$jL382@0l" name="confirmpassword" autocomplete="new-password" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="avatar out-group">
            <label>Select your avatar: </label>
            <input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/*" required />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" />
        <p>
            Already a member? <a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
    include('inc/footer.php');
?>
```

any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: replace $dirname = dirname(__DIR__) . '/images/';.  with $dirname = '../images/'; I guess u are trying to save/fetch your images in Image folder.

Comment: From where is the image to be viewed? From a page within the `demo/jobs/` folder or at all levels?

Comment: saving an image with the domain (ie: `www.example.com/project-dir/images/img.name` ) would not be a good idea ~ better to store just the `/project-dir/images/img.name` portion

Comment: @RamRaider the image to be viewed in user.php within the demo/jobs level

Answer (score 0):

```
$dirname = dirname(__DIR__) . '/images/';`enter code here`
```

replace that to

```
$dirname ='../images/';
```

or

```
$dirname = 'example.com/project-dir/images/';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a little play around - perhaps this might help you a little. I did test this and it all appears fine here. A couple of points to note:- do not try to hash a user's password using `MD5` - it has been considered `"broken"` for several years and there are vast dictionaries of known hashes which can be used to identify the password. Also - despite using `mysqli_real_escape_string` there is still potential danger of SQL injection due to the embedded variables and it is also possible that `mysqli_real_escape_string` will modify the value of certain strings which could complicate matters somewhat so you would be advised to use `prepared statements` with bound variables.

There are comments in the code which might help as well.

```
<?php


    try{
        /*
            it is more important to know whether or not the fields that are used
            in the SQL are present in the POST array than it is to know if the
            button has been pressed. It is possible to bypass the form afterall!
        */
        if( isset(
            $_POST['fullname'],
            $_POST['phone'],
            $_POST['username'],
            $_POST['email'],
            $_POST['password'],
            $_POST['confirmpassword']
        )){
            if( $_POST['password']!==$_POST['confirmpassword'] )throw new Exception('Passwords do not match');

            require 'config.php';

            $root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            $tmp=!empty( $_FILES['avatar'] ) ? $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'] : false;
            $name=!empty( $_FILES['avatar'] ) ? $_FILES['avatar']['name'] : false;
            $exts=['gif','png','jpg','jpeg'];


            if( $tmp && $name ){

                $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
                if( !in_array( $ext, $exts ) )throw new Exception( sprintf('The file extension "%s" is not allowed', $ext ) );
                if( !getimagesize( $tmp ) ) throw new Exception( sprintf('"%s" does not appear to be an image', $name ) );



                # The "Current Working Directory" is "/demo/jobs/lib/"
                # so the "images" folder is a level UP at "/demo/jobs/images"
                chdir( '../' );
                $cwd=getcwd();


                # The path used to save/move uploaded file
                # & should yield a path of the form:
                # /home/rainpeyi/public_html/demo/jobs/images/filename.jpg          
                $savepath = sprintf( '%s/images/%s', $cwd, $name );



                # The path to the `demo/jobs` folder
                $apppath =  str_replace( 
                                array( realpath( $root ), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ),
                                array( '', '/' ),
                                realpath( $cwd )
                            );

                # & should yield a path of the form:
                # /demo/jobs/images/filename.jpg
                $displaypath = sprintf( '%s/images/%s', $apppath, $name );



                if( is_object( $conn ) && is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) && move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $savepath ) ){
                    # safe sql statement with placeholders
                    $sql='insert into `candidates` 
                            ( `fullname`, `phone`, `username`, `email`, `pass`, `avatar` ) 
                        values 
                            ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )';

                    #MD5 is broken.. do NOT use for password hashing, ever!
                    $hash=password_hash( $_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT );

                    # create the `prepared statement` object & bind variables to placeholders
                    $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
                    $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $_POST['fullname'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $hash, $displaypath );

                    $result=$stmt->execute();
                    $rows=$stmt->affected_rows;

                    if( !$result or $rows==0 )throw new Exception( 'Unable to add user' );
                    else {
                        # all good.. user added, image saved
                        # redirect user

                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['message'] = "Registration Successful!";

                        exit( header('Location: user.php') );
                    }
                }else{
                    throw new Exception('File upload failed');
                }
            }else{
                throw new Exception('Bad foo! No file present');
            }
        }else{
            $tmp=[];
            $fields=array(
                'fullname',
                'phone',
                'username',
                'email',
                'password',
                'confirmpassword'
            );
            foreach( $fields as $field ){
                if( !in_array( $field, array_keys( $_POST ) ) )$tmp[]=$field;
            }
            throw new Exception( sprintf( 'One or more required fields are not present in the POST request!<br />%s', implode( '<br />', $tmp ) ) );
        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( $e->getMessage() );
    }
?>
```

Comment: am getting the first throw 'One or more required fields are not present in the POST request''

Comment: In which case check your form and ensure these fields exist and are named correctly - the POST variables are taken directly from your code - if it fails here it would have failed in your code too.

Comment: I just added from code above can you take a look please?

Comment: made a small change to let you know which fields are not present when the form is posted.

Comment: I have updated validate.php and it is now working with login form as well, can you take a look, please?

Comment: Only 'One or more required fields are not present in the POST request!' is showing, i am PHP novice, can you please take time to explain the code?

Comment: I see some minor changes to your original question ( which by the way you probably should not do) but I don't really see any changes that encompass some of what I posted. The code I posted was tested and worked OK - though admittedly it is different to yours. The later piece of code you added from `// LOGIN CANDIDATES` onwards - this is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection. Even worse - you have NOT accepted that `MD5` for passwords is bad and have used that in the newer code... `MD5` is broken
R.I.P